# Order of jQuery getJSON callbacks?

Tags: javascript, jquery

jQuery's `$.getJSON()` accepts callbacks for `done`, `fail`, and `always`

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/

I don't see a mention of which order these get called in. Can I expect that `done` and `fail` are always triggered before `always`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is fairly easy to test:
http://jsfiddle.net/2EnxL/

```
var d = new $.Deferred();
d.done(function () { console.log("done"); });
d.always(function () { console.log("always"); });
d.done(function () { console.log("done2"); });
d.always(function () { console.log("always2"); });
d.resolve();
```

Output:

```
done
always
done2
always2
```

So the callbacks are called **in order**. This also seems to make the most sense to me.

`always` is not like a `finally`, it's just a way to combine `fail` and `done`.

Answer (score 2):

This is in the documentation for all the Deferred callback methods

> When the Deferred is resolved or rejected, callbacks are executed in
>   the order they were added

[**Deferred.always** docs](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.always/)
[**Deferred.done** docs](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.done/)

Comment: maybe it is noteworthy, that $.getJSON, and other $.ajax functions return a $.jqXHR, which is inheriting $.Deferred